# NA / NaN / Inf on call to an external function (arg 5)

Tags: r, simulation

I have the following problem, I am generating random values and when I run the syntax I get the following error "NA / NaN / Inf in a call to an external function (arg 5)" but this error appears when there is text in the base (at least that I read), in this case it shouldn't happen.

It should be noted that the Ars command specifies the limits of the variable x, which is in the interval 0 <x <1. The problem occurs when executing the ARS command and the simulated values of "f" are only 0

```
library(ars)

f<-function(x){ 
               125*log(.5+(.25*x))+34*log(x)+38*log(1-x) +72*log(.25)
}


fprima<-function(x){ 
                    (125/(.2+.25*x))+(34/x)-(38/(1-x)) 
                    }


theta<-ars(n=10000,f,fprima,lb=TRUE,ub=TRUE,xlb=0,xub=1)


theta
```

Comment: Your `x` appears in denominators. Have you ensured that these denominators can't become 0? Your `x` appears in a logarithm. Have you ensured that the argument of the logarithm can become <= 0?

Comment: E.g., if `x=0` specifies some kind of starting value then `34/x` is `Inf` immediately.

Comment: @Roland the variable x if it is bounded

Comment: But you say "the simulated values are only zero".  Are the "simulated values" in `x`?  If so, @Roland has identified the problem.  Does `ars` calculate the range of `x`?  if so, that may be an issue, becase if `x` is "all zero", then so is its range.  We need clarity, which we don't have at the moment.

Comment: @Limey Hi, The simulated values of the function of x, x is bounded between 0 and 1 (0 <x <1)

Answer (score 0):

Add `message(x)` to `f` to see the x-values it gets passed. In your original code, you specified a starting value `x = 0` and that is passed to `f` regardless of specified boundaries. The same if you use the default starting values (as in the current iteration of your code).

The code runs if you specify a sane starting value:

```
theta<-ars(n=10000,f,fprima,lb=TRUE,ub=TRUE,xlb=0,xub=1, m = 1, x = 0.5)
```

However, you then get these internal errors:

```
Error in sobroutine sample_...
ifault= 5
```

According to the documentation this means "non-concavity detected".

It appears your `fprima` function is not correct. According to the documentation, it is supposed to be `d/du log(f(u,...))`. Based on `D(quote(125*log(.5+(.25*x))+34*log(x)+38*log(1-x) +72*log(.25)), "x")` I've corrected this:

```
fprima<-function(x){ 
  125 * (0.25/(0.5 + (0.25 * x))) + 34 * (1/x) - 38 * (1/(1 - x))
}
```

With that, the code runs fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! you are right the problem was my first derivative, I thought it expressed the same thing but it seems that I am wrong. Thanks